# trying to get coords from database but nothing happens

Tags: java, android

as you can see from the code below im just trying to get the coords pushed out to the logcat.  however i never see the message or the coords.  it shows me the sql string then finishes.  so i believe the try is failing but even the catch statement doesnt return anything.

```
Button ButtonMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButMap);
   ButtonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
           try {
         /* Query for some results with Selection and Projection. */
            String sql = "SELECT _id,Longitude,Latitude FROM " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id = "+ID;
          Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
           //db.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "Longitude", "Latitude"}, 
                      // "_id = " + "'%"+ID+"%'", null, null, null, null);
                  Log.e("SQL Select", sql);


         /* Get the indices of the Columns we will need */
         int longitude, latitude ;
            longitude = c.getColumnIndex("Longitude");
            latitude = c.getColumnIndex("Latitude");

         /* Check if our result was valid. */
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
           int i = 0;
           /* Loop through all Results */ 
           do {
            i++;
            /* Retrieve the values of the Entry
             * the Cursor is pointing to. */
             double lat = c.getDouble(latitude);
              double lon = c.getDouble(longitude);            
                         Log.e("GPS", "location for this record is: lat="+lat+", lon="+lon);

           } while (c.moveToNext());
          }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
                  Log.e("GPS", t.toString());
       }
           finally {
         if (db != null)
          db.close();
        }

            Intent intent = new Intent();
                 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                 finish();

       }

      });
 }
```

Comment: Since you see the query: Did you copy and paste the query, run sqlite3 in the shell, and enter the query? Did it return any rows?

Comment: try catching the exception catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} and tell us what the log says

Comment: the catch never triggers. (i never see  Log.e("GPS", t.toString());)   i never knew the sqlite3 thing ill have to investigate that and get back to you.  thanks for the replies.

Comment: ill keep searching here but i dont see how im suppose to get root access.  im following http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html  but get access is denied with doing adb -s.....

Comment: You shouldn't need root access. Worst case, you can write a little program that copies your database from your internal storage to "/sdcard", i.e. the SD card. From there, you can download it to your computer with `adb pull`. Or, if you have sqlite3 on your phone, you can use `adb shell` and run sqlite3 directly on your phone. Using sqlite3 on database files is incredibly useful. I'm quite certain the problem is that your query doesn't yield any results. Btw, in the sqlite3 tool, you can enter `.dump` to get the entire contents of your database.

Comment: well idk whats going on.  created a new avd (which of course gave me a new clean db) and now its working.  idk if its my code or the emulator but somthing is weird.  because this select statement happens after viewing a list of whats already in the db.  so i dont get how it could show these rows when querying everything in the table but no results when queried individually.  thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

been to long to know exactly what fixed it but here is the answer code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class SqlLiteFishLoggerDao extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements
        FishLoggerDao {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "fishingLog";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "LogEntries";

    private static final String DELETE_LOG_ENTRY_SQL = "DELETE FROM LogEntries WHERE _id = ?;";

    private static final String FIND_LOG_ENTRY_SQL = "SELECT * FROM LogEntries WHERE _id = ?";

    private static final String FIND_ALL_ENTRIES_SQL = "SELECT * FROM LogEntries";

    private static final String[] NO_ARGS = {};

    private Context context;

    private SQLiteDatabase DB;

    public SqlLiteFishLoggerDao(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteLogEntry(String id) {
        DB = getWritableDatabase();
        DB.execSQL(DELETE_LOG_ENTRY_SQL, new Object[] { id });
        DB.close();
    }

    @Override
    public LogEntry findEntry(String id) {
        DB = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery(FIND_LOG_ENTRY_SQL,
                new String[] { id });
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return null;
        }
        LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
        entry.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        entry.setEntryDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CreateDate")));
        entry.setSpecies(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Species")));
        entry.setSizeOrWeight(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SizeOrWeight")));
        entry.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Latitude")));
        entry.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longitude")));
        entry.setPictureUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PictureURL")));

        cursor.close();
        DB.close();
        return entry;

    }

    @Override
    public void insertLogEntry(LogEntry entry) {
        DB = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Latitude", entry.getLatitude());
        values.put("Longitude", entry.getLongitude());
        values.put("PictureURL", entry.getPictureUrl());
        values.put("SizeOrWeight", entry.getSizeOrWeight());
        values.put("CreateDate", entry.getEntryDate());
        values.put("Species", entry.getSpecies());
        DB.insertOrThrow("LogEntries", null, values);
        DB.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String s;
        try {
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i = 0; i < statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                db.execSQL(s);
            }
            Log.e("DB", "DB Created Successfully");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("DB error: ",t.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<LogEntry> findAllEntries() {
        DB = getReadableDatabase();

        List<LogEntry> entries = new ArrayList<LogEntry>();

        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery(FIND_ALL_ENTRIES_SQL,
                NO_ARGS);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
                entry.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                entry.setEntryDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CreateDate")));
                entry.setSpecies(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Species")));
                entry.setSizeOrWeight(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SizeOrWeight")));
                entry.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Latitude")));
                entry.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longitude")));
                entry.setPictureUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PictureURL")));

                if (entry.getSpecies() == null) {
                    entry.setSpecies("Not Entered");
                }

                if (entry.getSizeOrWeight() == null) {
                    entry.setSizeOrWeight("Not entered");
                }

                entries.add(entry);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        DB.close();
        return entries;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        DB = getWritableDatabase();
        DB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(getWritableDatabase());
        DB.close();
    }
}
```